# TinyXML2 could not parse a XML file witch contains utf16 encoding

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tinyxml2

I try to use `tinyxml2` lib to parse my xml file, which contains some text displays as Chinese language, while, when I got the result, it shows something wrong.

How should I do, anyone can help?

Comment: In the question it's written "_it shows something wrong_". Could you provide some more details? For instance the command and the error message and the relevant source code.

Comment: I think the XML text file is usually UTF-8 encoded? You might have to do conversions on the text to get your string. I am not sure. But you have show no code nor sample XML data.

Comment: Thany you for your kindly reminder @Erik Sjölund @ Andrew Truckle, I finally give up TinyXNL2, and I currently use xerces-c_3D.lib, it works very well. Thanks